# C++ Loops - Flow bug?

Tags: c++, loops, input

In my programming class, we have been tasked with writing a program to convert a word or phrase into a phone number, evaluating each character and translating it into a corresponding number.

Here's the code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    int noOfLetters;
    char response;

    cout << "Enter Y/y to convert a telephone number " 
         << "form letters to digits.\n"
         << "Enter any other letter to terminate the program: ";

    cin >> response;
    cout << endl;

    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y')
    {

        cout << "Enter a telephone number using letters: ";
        cin >> letter;

        noOfLetters = 0;

        cout << "The corresponding telephone number is: ";

        while (noOfLetters != 7)
        {
            //cout << "[" << noOfLetters << "]";
            noOfLetters++;

            switch (toupper(letter))
            {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                cout << 2;
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                cout << 3;
                break;
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
                cout << 4;
                break;
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                cout << 5;
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'N':
            case 'O':
                cout << 6;
                break;
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
            case 'S':
                cout << 7;
                break;
            case 'T':
            case 'U':
            case 'V':
                cout << 8;
                break;
            case 'W':
            case 'X':
            case 'Y':
            case 'Z':
                cout << 9;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "[invalid]";
            }

            if (noOfLetters == 3)
            {
                cout << '-';
            }
            else if (noOfLetters > 7)
            {
                cin.ignore();
            }
            cin >> letter;

            //noOfLetters++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');

        cout << "\nTo process another telephone number, enter Y/y \n"
             << "Enter any other letter to terminate the program: ";
        cin >> response;
       }
}
```

Everything works fine, provided I type more than 7 characters. The issue is, if I type exactly 7 characters, it messes itself up.

Say I type "honk honk" (which measures 8 characters excluding spaces) and run through the program. The output would be as follows:

> Enter Y/y to convert a telephone number form letters to digits. Enter
>   any other letter to terminate the program: y
>
> Enter a telephone number using letters: honk honk The corresponding
>   telephone number is: 466-5466
>
> To process another telephone number, enter Y/y Enter any other letter
>   to terminate the program: n Press any key to continue . . .

So, that works fine. But if I input "seventy" (exactly 7 characters), the program forces me to enter another character (excluding spaces and newlines) before continuing, like so:

> Enter Y/y to convert a telephone number form letters to digits. Enter
>   any other letter to terminate the program: y
>
> Enter a telephone number using letters: seventy The corresponding
>   telephone number is: 738-3689 h
>
> To process another telephone number, enter Y/y Enter any other letter
>   to terminate the program: n Press any key to continue . . .

I'm wanting to modify the program so that I will able to enter a 7-character phrase into the program and have it run correctly without any errors, such as when I enter anything measuring 8 characters or more.

I have tried all that I can do, with no luck. Could someone make a suggestion to help me fix this bug?

Comment: Remove the `cin >> letter` outside the `while` and move the `cin >> letter` inside the `while` at it beginning will solve it. The problem is that you are getting the first letter outside the `while` and only sum the `noOfLetters` inside. That means the `noOfLetters` will always be 1 less than it actually is. The current order of things are: cin, while check, increase int. You need to change to cin, increase, check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the following patch (with the aim to be minimal):

```
***************
*** 83,91 ****
              {
                  cout << '-';
              }
!             else if (noOfLetters > 7)
              {
!                 cin.ignore();
              }
              cin >> letter;

--- 83,91 ----
              {
                  cout << '-';
              }
!             else if (noOfLetters == 7)
              {
!                 break;
              }
              cin >> letter;
```

What you perhaps are not realizing is that input is buffered: until you press Enter the program does not see anything. It hangs on the first `cin >> letter`, outside the loop, **until you press enter**. The subsequent `cin >> letter` in the loop read from the buffer, which therefore always contains a newline as last character.

The way you read the buffer, it is skipping whitespace however (the default), so you never see the newline.

After the loop you have a `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` which ignores everything (remaining) uptil and including the newline (note that this function is not skipping whitespace: the 100 are including whitespace characters). So, the simplest thing to do is just leave the loop as soon as you processed 7 characters.

With the original code, when you type precisely 7 characters, all are read and processed at which point noOfLetters == 7, which is not > 7.. so you try to read one more character which hangs because the remaining new-line is skipped as whitespace and there is nothing else to be read yet: you have to type at least one non-white space character (to be processed) followed by the Enter key in order to return from the `cin >> letter;` at all.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic flow is a bit messed up.  Note that when `noOfLetters` is seven, you still ask for another letter at the end of your while loop.  Consider instead reading at the top of the loop.  If it makes it easier, buffer up the output in the loop.

```
cout << "Enter a telephone number using letters: " << flush;
// Flush may be necessary if output is line-buffered  ^

noOfLetters = 0;

// This is a buffer where we will be storing the output phone number so that we
// don't have to deal with mixing input with output.
//
// You will need to "#include <sstream>".
stringstream phoneNumber;

// Reading becomes part of the loop condition; if the end of the input is reached,
// we want the loop to terminate.  "cin >> letter" will evaluate to false in
// boolean context if reading failed.
//
// Note that && short-circuits; if the left side is false then the right side is
// not even evaluated.  So when noOfLetters == 7, the loop terminates without
// reading another character.
while (noOfLetters != 7 && cin >> letter) {
    ++noOfLetters;

    // Your switch block goes here. Replace "cout" with "phoneNumber".

    if (noOfLetters == 3) phoneNumber << '-';
}

cout << "The corresponding telephone number is: " << phoneNumber.rdbuf() << endl;
```